Multinomial theorem for matrices
The multinomial theorem asserts that
$$(x_1+\cdots + x_k)^n = \sum_{n_1+\cdots +n_k = n,\ n_1,\dots,n_k\geq0} \frac{n!}{n_1! \cdots n_k!}x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_k^{n_l}.$$
How does this fomrula change when we replace $x_1,\dots, x_k$ with matrices $A_1,\dots, A_k$? That is, how would one express $(A_1+\cdots A_k)^m$ as above? I suspect now that the order of multiplication matters, one would have to rather sum over all products of $A_1,\dots,A_k$ of length $n$. Would this be correct, and if so, how would one write out the formula?

Even binomial theorem fails for matrices.

How does the formula change? You get much more terms. Specifically, $k^n$ terms, compared to $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ terms in the binomial theorem.

Also, which switch from $n$ in the binomial theorem to $m$ in your new formula. It is harder to write about comparing them with $m$ in the second part.

Formula works for commuting matrices.

The order of multiplication now matters so much that it is not possible to collect any like terms at all; the result is now a sum of $k^n$ terms, each of which is different. For example $n = k = 2$ looks like
$$(x_1 + x_2)^2 = x_1^2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_1 + x_2^2.$$
In general we can write it as follows. Consider the set $W_{k, n}$ of all words $w$ on the alphabet $\{ x_1, \dots x_k \}$ of length $n$; we can think of each word as a noncommutative monomial in the $x_i$, so e.g. we interpret the word $x_1 x_1 x_2 x_1$ as the noncommutative monomial $x_1^2 x_2 x_1$. Then for arbitrary noncommuting $x_i$,
$$(x_1 + \dots + x_k)^n = \sum_{w \in W_{k, n}} w.$$
This is in some sense a tautology; if you ask for a precise definition of what a word is, it is basically exactly the set of terms in the expansion of $(x_1 + \dots + x_k)^n$! That's why nobody has bothered to call this result the "noncommutative multinomial theorem" or whatever. The RHS is pretty much just "the thing you get if you multiply out the LHS."
If we write $W_k = \bigsqcup_n W_{k, n}$ for the set of all words on the alphabet $\{ x_1, \dots x_k \}$, not specifying length, then it follows that we have the "noncommutative generating function" identity
$$\frac{1}{1 - (x_1 + \dots + x_k)} = \sum_{w \in W_k} w.$$
Variations of this idea can be used to produce noncommutative generating functions describing various classes of words; there's some material about this in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. II.

If $[k]$ denotes the set $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ then
$$(A_1 + A_2+\cdots + A_k)^m = \sum_{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m)\in[k]^m}A_{i_1}A_{i_2}\cdots A_{i_m}$$
but I agree with Qiaochu Yuan's answer: this is not useful because you're just saying that you'll get all possible terms when you distribute the product, which you already know if you know how distributivity works.

The purpose of the multinomial/binomial theorem is that it makes use of the commutativity to collect terms with the same factors. The issue for matrices, is that they do not commute, thus you cannot collect terms. For examples
$$
(A+B)^3 = A^3 + \underbrace{A^2 B + ABA + B A^2}_{= 3A^2 B \text{ when $A$ and $B$ commute}} + \underbrace{AB^2 + BAB + B^2 A}_{= 3A B^2 \text{ when $A$ and $B$ commute}} + B^3.
$$
One way you could write the binomial theorem is
$$
(A+B)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \underline{A^k B^{n-k}}
$$
Where $\underline{A^i B^j}$ is the sum of these factors in all possible orders. This notation has the nice property that for any constants $\lambda, \mu$, $\underline{(\lambda A)^i (\mu B)^j} = \lambda^i \mu^j\underline{A^i B^j}$. For the multinomial theorem, this translates to
$$
(A_1+\ldots+A_k)^n = \sum_{n_1 + \ldots + n_k = n} \underline{A_1^{n_1} \cdots A_k^{n_k}}.
$$
